# How to define a function with a function type parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

I could define a function like this

```
func doWithAction(action: ()-> void) {
    // something
}
```

However, when I use the function, the auto-completion of Xcode give me a block/closure

```
self.addPullToRefreshControllerWithAction { () -> void in

}
```

I know closure and function are something same in Swift, but I want to lead the one who use this function to pass a function in, not a block. The reason why I do this is I want this function to behave like a selector and a delegation

Comment: This is like saying you want your function to accept integers, but not integer variables. You can't do that distinction. Functions are closures, and anonymous closures are closures. You want to accept a closure. You can't say which kind, from the receiver's perspective they're all the same.

Comment: Closures are the modern name for blocks, and closures are functions, as @kap points out in his answer.  You are/were confused by the syntactic shortcut that allows you to pass a trailing closure to a function that has a closure as its last argument.  ie. foo(f:{}) is the same as foo() {}.  kap's answer is correct and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

yes, closure and functions are practically the same in swift, so if the function expects a closure, you can pass a function with the same signature as a parameter instead. like this

```
func iAmAFunc(() -> Void) -> Void {
    //do stuff
}

func funcThatTakesVoidAndReturnsVoid() -> Void {
    //do stuff
}

var closureThatTakesVoidAndReturnsVoid: () -> Void = { }

iAmAFunc(funcThatTakesVoidAndReturnsVoid)
iAmAFunc(closureThatTakesVoidAndReturnsVoid)
```